# Is it possible to confirm ownership of a (PowerPoint) file?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, logging, metadata, ownership

My friend is in a legal situation where he needs to confirm he created a certain PowerPoint presentation. The presentation was subsequently plagiarised and pasted into a PhD thesis by his former boss.

Is there any way this can be done in a legally watertight manner? We have the file, and access to the computer it was created on.

It seems that metadata can be edited, so maybe there's another way. For example, are change logs stored in the PowerPoint file itself?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned metadata can be modified, so first part of the answer is: NO, there is no way you can prove based on file metadata that you're the author of a file.

However, you can find another ways: e-mails sent with the file before it was published, conversations in e-mails, eventually old backups in the cloud where timestamp can't be modified by you...

Comment: Thanks Mate. Yes, we do have email conversations with the file attached, even some emails having the eventual plagiariser as the recipient, so that's quite incriminating I believe.